# Dynamically adding "active" class to a link based on the current url in thymeleaf and spring boot 3

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-boot-3

Working with spring boot 3 and thymeleaf. I have a base layout for my dashboard which has some link items. I want to give the currently active link an "active" bootstrap class appended to it. How do i get the current url in my thymeleaf template?

I tried this but i keep getting errors in the log

```
th:classappend="${#request.getRequestURI() == '/application'? 'active': ''}"
```

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.getRequestURI() == '/application'? 'active': ''" (template: "/fragments/layouts/dash" - line 378, col 41)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#request.getRequestURI() == '/application'? 'active': ''" (template: "/fragments/layouts/dash" - line 378, col 41)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'request','session','servletContext' and 'response' expression utility objects are no longer available by default for template expressions and their use is not recommended. In cases where they are really needed, they should be manually added as context variables.
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionObjectFactory.buildObject(StandardExpressionObjectFactory.java:207) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SpringStandardExpressionObjectFactory.buildObject(SpringStandardExpressionObjectFactory.java:110) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.DialectSetConfiguration$AggregateExpressionObjectFactory.buildObject(DialectSetConfiguration.java:785) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.expression.ExpressionObjects.getObject(ExpressionObjects.java:108) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.ThymeleafEvaluationContext.lookupVariable(ThymeleafEvaluationContext.java:134) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.lookupVariable(ExpressionState.java:172) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.VariableReference.getValueInternal(VariableReference.java:79) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:61) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:97) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpEQ.getValueInternal(OpEQ.java:42) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpEQ.getValueInternal(OpEQ.java:32) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:212) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Ternary.getValueInternal(Ternary.java:54) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:338) ~[spring-expression-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 161 common frames omitted

2024-03-22T08:28:03.156+01:00 ERROR 56470 --- [Gocobac] [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/pDashboard.html]")] with root cause
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'request','session','servletContext' and 'response' expression utility objects are no longer available by default for template expressions and their use is not recommended. In cases where they are really needed, they should be manually added as context variables.` The actual way is as pointed out by passing a specific var to the model.